# в чем ошибка надо поменять картинки можете взять любые

Tags: javascript

Дан блок .div-9. Внутри блока - изображение 1.png. При клике правой кнопкой мыши  - меняйте изображение на 2.png. Надеюсь вы догадаетесь изменить только src изображения? */[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

function t9() {

```
let x = document.querySelector('.div-9');


x.src.replace(1, 2);
console.log(document.querySelector('img').src);
}
document.querySelector('.div-9').oncontextmenu = t9
```

--------------------

**Task 9.**

Дан блок .div-9. Внутри блока - изображение 1.png. При клике правой кнопкой мыши -
                меняйте изображение на 2.png. Надеюсь вы догадаетесь изменить только src изображения?

```
            <div class="div-9 block">
                <img src="img/1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="out-9">
            </div>
    </section>
```